# Is there any way to use the information returned from tomcat server in Java EE in an applet / any java application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet

I want to use the clients to request IP addresses of other clients that are also requesting the IP addresses from the server, that is like a chat,

example:

client A requests IP address of available clients from server S. The client B also requests the IP address of available clients from server S. The server S sees two clients, and returns to client A the IP address of client B and it returns to client B the IP address of client A.
Now I want to use the returned IP addresses in my applet (a multiplayer game involving sockets). Is there is any way to use the returned IP address from tomcat server S in my applet which may or may not be in a JSP page?

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a JavaScript variable or form hidden field. Then acces that from your applet